# Software Updater getting worse ... now worst

Tags: 20.04, package-management, updates, update-manager

I've had *Not all updates can be installed* problems with Software Updater for quite some time.  Now it has gotten to a blank screen with a large download of (blankety-blank-)blank. Running Software Updater gets:

> Checking for Updates...
> Updated Software is available for this computer...

However, the *Details of updates* and *Technical description* sections are blank. Yet it says that *331.5 MB will be downloaded.*

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Software Updater not showing]

So am I expected to download 300+ MB of secret files, so secret they have no names?

I have been dealing with *Not all updates can be installed* for some time.  Searching seems to imply this is a problem with the repositories or package dependencies, and to wait until they get straightened out - but *MONTHS* of waiting?

The only suggestion Software Updater offers is a *Partial Upgrade* (to what? Release 21.666.7734?) but I use LTS for a reason: I don't want Upgrades every week (or even month);  I do not want to be a member of the Bug-Of-The-Month Club, and some other postings indicate the *Partial Upgrade* is a bad idea.

Nothing offers any clue as to what is wrong. Synaptic shows
*86901 packages listed, 25535 installed, 0 broken, 0 to install/upgrade, 0 to remove* and various suggestions from searching seem to be "*turn the software loose and trust us*" such as `sudo apt-get upgrade` and hope the stuff that's not working fixes itself...

If we can't depend on and trust the software that is updating our systems, we're in trouble.  How do I get out of this trouble?

Here are my OS details:

- Ubuntu MATE 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit
- Kernel Linux 5.18.10-76051810-generic x86_64
- MATE 1.24.0

---

As [requested by @user535733](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493069/software-updater-getting-worse-now-worst#comment2615849_1493069):

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease 
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu xenial [114 kB]
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease      
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/heyarje/makemkv-beta/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Fetched 114 kB in 1s (79.2 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
32 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

```
$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done  
apt-utils/focal-updates 2.0.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.9]  
apt/focal-updates 2.0.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.9]  
fwupd-signed/focal 1:1.1-4pop0~1643174914~20.04~f30da97~dev amd64 [upgradable from: 1.5.11- 0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev]  
gnome-firmware/focal-updates 3.34.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.34.0-2]  
intel-microcode/focal-updates,focal-security 3.20231114.0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.20230808.0ubuntu0.20.04.1]  
libapt-pkg6.0/focal-updates 2.0.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.9]  
libreoffice-base-core/focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-base-drivers/focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-base/focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-calc/focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-common/focal,focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 all [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-core/focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-draw/focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-gnome/focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-gtk3/focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-help-common/focal,focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 all [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-help-en-us/focal,focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 all [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-impress/focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-math/focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
libreoffice-writer/focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
linux-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security 5.15.0.88.98~20.04.46 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0.67.74~20.04.28]  
linux-generic/focal 6.0.12.76060012.202212290932~1683754412~20.04~3254e87~dev amd64 [upgradable from: 5.18.10.76051810.202207071639~1659403207~20.04~cb5f582~dev]  
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security 5.15.0.88.98~20.04.46 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0.67.74~20.04.28]  
linux-headers-generic/focal 6.0.12.76060012.202212290932~1683754412~20.04~3254e87~dev amd64 [upgradable from: 5.18.10.76051810.202207071639~1659403207~20.04~cb5f582~dev]  
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security 5.15.0.88.98~20.04.46 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0.67.74~20.04.28]  
linux-image-generic/focal 6.0.12.76060012.202212290932~1683754412~20.04~3254e87~dev amd64 [upgradable from: 5.18.10.76051810.202207071639~1659403207~20.04~cb5f582~dev]  
linux-system76/focal 6.0.12.76060012.202212290932~1683754412~20.04~3254e87~dev amd64 [upgradable from: 5.18.10.76051810.202207071639~1659403207~20.04~cb5f582~dev]  
python3-uno/focal 4:7.6.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4:7.5.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1]  
shim-signed/focal-updates,focal-security 1.40.9+15.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.40.7+15.4-0ubuntu9]  
system76-driver/focal,focal 20.04.82~1699289493~20.04~dfbce5b~dev all [upgradable from: 20.04.81~1695239320~20.04~ec593da~dev]  
system76-firmware-daemon/focal 1.0.55~1699483593~20.04~cb768e7~dev amd64 [upgradable from: 1.0.54~1698255341~20.04~75cb1f6~dev]  
ubuntu-advantage-tools/focal-updates 30~20.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 29.4~20.04]
```

Not wanting to run `sudo apt upgrade` until the problem is at least diagnosed, if not fixed, since it makes changes as it wishes.  With the Software Updater failing (blank list for 300+ MB of changes), more changes can make things worse.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1493069/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of `sudo apt upgrade`. Keep in mind that we are your peer users and volunteers -- avoid hyperbole and **shouting** and rhetorical questions, as it scares away knowledgeable folks who otherwise could help you.

Comment: The MATE desktop is a *flavor* and is EOL as is no longer supported by the Ubuntu MATE team (https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-20-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/26477) so there are no updates there. You're details show you using a non-Ubuntu managed kernel (it was a *testing* kernel only in Ubuntu) from 20.10 which has long been EOL & thus isn't supported.  What are you running? as your kernel is non-Ubuntu which could be reason for your issues, are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu MATE 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 5.18.10-76051810-generic x86_64
MATE 1.24.0

Comment: 5.18.10-76051810-generic is not a Ubuntu kernel but a POP OS kernel used by Pop OS created by System 76 (*as encoded within the kernel details*).  The 5.18 kernel was used by [Ubuntu 20.10 which is EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/) though also used by 20.04 using HWE, but Ubuntu systems upgraded to 20.04.3 prior to 20.10's EOL & thus weren't using 5.18 any longer.  If your system was Ubuntu at install, it's now been *polluted* with Pop OS and thus your issues; you've turned your system into a *frakensystem* most likely

Comment: Can you run `update-manager` and post the output?

Comment: @guiverc It could be that OP bought a System76 computer, where the OEM installation had a Pop OS kernel for better hardware support (however, this is just my speculation). In any case, installing a non-official kernel should not cause update manager to stop working (as APT is not broken).

Comment: System 76 documented problems with their PPAs when used with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which created breakage, for their own installed systems they had specific *pinning* put in place to prevent this breakage, but it was common for users who had Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but wanted some of Pop OS benefits to not add that pinning (*it had to be manually added if the PPA was added*) thus the warnings put out by System 76. I'm not sure if those warnings still exist; but we at *Ubuntu News* didn't run them (*so I can't look hem up*) as it was outside of Ubuntu support (*we deemed*)  @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi - Aha!  We may be on to something - it is a System76 (Kudo Pro), but it is a virgin install of Ubuntu MATE from cdimage.ubuntu,com/ubuntu-mate/releases/20.04/release of the ubuntu-mate-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso and I built the USB myself (and still have it).

Comment: @guiverc - However, I have 'ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu focal main' in my repository list (Other Software) for drivers, etc.  -- Cold it have pulled in a kernel from there for some reason?  And could that have broken everything?

Comment: Finding problem - it is a matter of some PPA.  Remove several, Updater shows correct window, populated.  Put them back in,and blank window again.  Now working on tracking down exactly which PPA(s) cause trouble.

Comment: Remove System76 PPA mentioned above (only), and Software Updater gives valid window, with long list to be updated.  Will send email to System76 Support about problem.

Answer (score 3):

Got it! It was a problem interacting with the System76 PPA. I unchecked just that PPA and both problems disappeared:  the Software Updater gives a proper update window, and does not have the *Not all updates can be installed* issue nor anything about a *Partial Upgrade*.

Still running kernel 5.18.10-76051810-generic, so I will have to figure out how to get over to the correct kernel; several postings deal with that problem.

I will email this information to System76 support. We can hope they can figure out what's wrong with their PPA.

(Question for guiverc - how did you know that was not an Ubuntu-MATE kernel, and where can we find such information/documentation?  And Thank You very much.)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS provides 5.4 as the GA kernel, which is the default for *flavors* (ie. Ubuntu MATE) at 20.04 & 20.04.1, with later media using the HWE kernel stack (20.04.2 & later). At 20.04.2 the 5.18 kernel from 20.10, which is changed to 5.11 at 20.04.3 (from 21.04), 5.13 at 20.04.4 (from 21.10) & finally ceased upgrade at 5.15 at 20.04.5 (5.15 being the GA kernel stack of 22.04). Other OEM kernel options do exist; but your details showed a System 76 (*76051810*) rather than Ubuntu code.  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for some HWE details if useful

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve the bug with the software updater not displaying the available upgrades. However, you can see the available upgrades from `apt list --upgradable`, and it is completely safe to upgrade via the command line.

You can use the command `sudo apt full-upgrade`, so that Ubuntu installs all the updates available for your particular release, but does not upgrade (or partial upgrade) to a later version of Ubuntu.